# do while doesn't work

Tags: javascript, do-while

I'm building a website but a JavaScript part doesn't work.
Look here the script:

```js
    do {
      if (percen === 0) {
        console.log();
      } else if (percen === 1) {
        document.getElementById("percen").innerHTML = "Text"
      } else if (percen === 2) {
        document.getElementById("percen").innerHTML = "Text"
      } else if (clicks === 3) {
        ++percen;
      } else if (clicks === 4) {
        ++percen;
      } else if (clicks === 5) {
        ++percen;
      } else if (clicks === 6) {
        ++percen;
      } else if (clicks === 7) {
        var percen = 0;
      }
    }
```

But when I run it in a HTML file it will not loop.  The var "percen" will ++ when you use a button.

Comment: *"do while doesn't work"* - Where is the `while`?

Comment: Also don't declare `percen` again (with `var percen = 0`). Do it only once before you start looping.

Comment: Your browser has a console where it tells you about syntax errors, please find it (it's sometimes after the F12 short-cut). There's absolutely no need to play the guess game.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the 'while' portion of the 'do while' loop at the end:

```
do {
    if (percen === 0) {
        console.log();
    }

    // rest of your code
    // ...
}
while (percen < 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the condition at the end.. It is `while(condition)` remember that the condition is checked at the end of the script so it will enter 1 time. If you want you can do a while syntax `while(cond){yourscript}`